# hover сдвигает другой контент

Tags: css3, html5

Всем привет,
Есть вопрос у меня есть карточки 3*3 и вот у них есть `hover{border: 1px solid #d6d6d6, padding: 10px}`

И при наведение на карточки сам `hover`, то появляется но вместе с ним другие карточки немного сдвигаются и все контент сайта тоже.

Так вот как задать это hover фиксировано? Я что-то слышал мол через `absolute` можно, но при установке `position: absolute` для *hover* который делает *border* все начинает ломатся.

Comment: добавьте код, так сложно будет разобраться

Comment: задаешь элементам изначально прозрачный бордер: `border: 1px solid transparent` и при ховере просто меняешь его цвет.

Comment: @ПоляковРоман Вот ссылка секция "КАТАЛОГ ПРОДУКЦИИ"

Comment: https://codepen.io/vova-fish/pen/povxQrK

Comment: https://vovafish.github.io/vovafish/

Comment: вместо border можно использовать box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d6d6d6;

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 10px;
}

div:hover {
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```